# How to solve error importing pytesseract - f"{tesseract_cmd} is not installed or it's not in your PATH."

Tags: python, windows, ocr, tesseract

I've installed tesseract from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
Following this I also installed `pip install pytesseract` and also `pip install tesseract`

I've included "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR" in my PATH in the environment variables.

When I execute the following code:

```py
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('News.png')))
```

I get an error in the first line as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\Project\Breach\Tesseract_import2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytesseract
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .pytesseract import ALTONotSupported
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 89
    f"{tesseract_cmd} is not installed or it's not in your PATH."
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

I can use tesseract using Command Prompt and get the required results, however, it doesn't work on python for me.
I am using SublimeText3 for writing my script.

I've also tried using `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"`

Comment: Run the program using Python 3.6+, `f` strings are supported then

Comment: Thank you! This worked. 
Was this problem in the tesseract code?

Comment: Yes, it was the problem in tesseract